# Having trouble with divide and conquer algorithm for adding consecutive pairs of ints in an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, divide-and-conquer

So I am attempting to get my head around the divide and conquer principle and multiple recursive calls in a single method. It's going ok but I have a problem with the output of the method I am writing.

The purpose of the method is to return the sum of all the pairs of consecutive numbers in an array. I am 95% there but am not getting the output I expect and have been banging me head against the desk for ages trying to work out why.

The array is:

```
int[] array = { 11, 6, 87, 32, 15, 5, 9, 21 };
```

and the method is:

```
public int consecutivePairsSum_DivideAndConquer(int start, int end, int[] array) {
    int leftSum;
    int rightSum;
    int middle = (start + end) / 2;
    if (start == middle) {
        return array[middle];
    } else {
        leftSum = array[start] + array[start + 1];
        leftSum += consecutivePairsSum_DivideAndConquer(start, middle, array);
    }
    if (middle == end) {
        return array[end];
    } else {
        rightSum = array[middle] + array[middle+1];
        rightSum += consecutivePairsSum_DivideAndConquer(middle+1, end, array);
    }
    return leftSum + rightSum;
}
```

Here's my method call:

```
System.out.println(rF.consecutivePairsSum_DivideAndConquer(0, array.length-1, array));
```

I think it must be something to do with how I have split the array but no amount of experimenting is giving me the right output.

Expected output: 340

Actual output: 330

Any suggestions most welcome, this is driving me nuts! :p

ps Any useful links to where I can find a solid online tutorial/good book about recursion would also be great (if that's within the scope of SO seeing how it's not direct help with a programming issue)

Comment: If I remove a number like 5 from the array the sum goes up! Hmm.

Comment: Oh yeah just did it as well and it went up?! This recursion stuff is really complicated to grasp, especially with multiple branches

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant question: Why would you calculate this sum using recursion? This problem doesn't seem to be a good fit for a divide and conquer approach, although it can be done.

Comment: It's a task I've been given as a way to practice divide and conquer algorithms. It seems that a lot of practice q's to understand these concepts aren't particularly practical, they're just there to help your understanding of the principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline of the algorithm:

Base case: If your array has less than two elements, the result is `0` (because there are no pairs).

Otherwise: Divide the array into two halves, calculate the results for left and right halves, then the result for the whole array would be `<result of left half> + <result of right half> + <last element of left half> + <first element of right half>` (Because the only pair missing here is the pair at the location of the split).

In java, it would be something like this:

```
int consPairSum(int[] array, int left, int right) {
    if(right <= left + 1) return 0;

    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    int leftPairSum = consPairSum(array, left, mid);
    int rightPairSum = consPairSum(array, mid, right);
    return leftPairSum + rightPairSum + array[mid - 1] + array[mid];
}
```

It should be called as

```
consPairSum(array, 0, array.length);
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I've been after. This follows the divide and conquer principle and is really clean and readable. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

who said divide and conquer needs to divide into equal chunks you just need to divide into self similar problem. almost 1 liner.

```
static private int doTheThing(int[] list){
    if (list.length==2)
        return list[0]+list[1];
    return list[0]+list[1]+doTheThing(Arrays.copyOfRange(list,1,list.length));
}
```

Comment: It's just recursion, divide and conquer is supposed to simplify the problem exponentially on each division, it can also be run in parallel.